# Numerical Evaluation of a Series at a Point

Tags: numerical-methods, power-series

I have a numerical calculus challenge to resolve using a C++ algorithm or  scilab.
The problem is the following:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}x^{n}$

where $a_{n}=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$

This function is defined for $-1\leqslant x<1$

I need to evaluate the function with 10 correct digits  at:
$$f(0.99)$$
$$f(0.999)$$
$$f(-1)$$

For the first one I tried to use brute force to stop the series at its 1000000th part and it worked pretty well. But for the second, it needs a lot more to get where I need and for the third I cant get anywhere near where it stops to grow.

I tried to find in  the internet numerical methods to evaluate series but I was unable to find. Do you have any hint about how can I get this values with less cost?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried expanding $a_n$ at $n=\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea I have is to consider the behavior of the coefficient for large $n$:

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} \sim \frac1{2 n}$$

And we know that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2 n} = -\frac12 \log{(1-x)} $$

So...numerically find the sum

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left (\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} - \frac1{2 n} \right ) x^n $$

and the sum you want is $f(x) \approx g(x) - \frac12 \log{(1-x)} $.  Note that the you can get about $10^{-5}$ accuracy with $N=25$ terms, even better with smaller $x$.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a plot of 1,000,000 terms of the original series vs. 1000 terms of the new series representation with the log term.  Here I plotted approximations of

$$f\left (1-10^{-x} \right ) $$

for $x\in [1,4]$.

[image]

The plot in red is the new series, while the plot in blue, with the discontinuity at $3.0$, is the original series.  Clearly there is some problem with the original series; this is why I trust the new series.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will take a closer look at this.

Comment: Will See, thanks

Comment: Should I use directly this series or I need to combine it with the original one for small numbers of N?

With 1000000 terms in the original series I get $$f(0.99)= 2.195222125969864$$

And with 1000 terms in the new series I get $$f(0.99)=2.19516038952891223$$ and this number doesn't change when N gets bigger.

So there is a diference in the 5th digit

Comment: @AqueleMesmo: I honestly would trust the new series.  You are using an extremely large number of terms, with a term in which subtraction error is a major problem.  I have been seeing this in Mathematica as well.

Comment: Yeah, I made in my Texas calculator and the new series is good enough. Probably some error in my calculation for this such a big number of terms. Thank you very much for your help. Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you for the addendum. And I checkmarked this. Thank you